# Booting from bootable USB

Tags: boot, system-installation

My laptop (Lenovo ideapad 100) currently has linux mint 18.1 os.

I boots using sandisk 16-GB USB. Linux mint has USB Image Formatter and USB Image Writer, which I use to format and to make USB bootable(By writing image on to USB). I downloaded ISO image files for Debian and others.

I made the USB bootable for other os such as Debian and tried to install them, which is not fruitful.

But it works well if I use to install any version of Linux mint such as 17.2, 18 etc.,

I tried legacy support, ufei etc., in boot setup. File system is tried for FAT32 and also NTFS. Why USB becoming bootable only for Linux mint os? What I have to do to make it bootable for other os?

Comment: Are you trying the `dd` command ?

Comment: You can use Unebootin for many linux distro.You just format usb flash disk as fat32.

Comment: Can you show from mint `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS` so we know in which mode it is installt? And `sudo dmidecode -t 0`

Comment: I tried dd command but didn't solve @GAD3R

Comment: Unetbootin worked  correctly @supriady

Answer (score 0):

To create a debian bootable USB from Linux machine you can use the command `dd` or the command `cp` as recommended on the official website.

Using `dd` :

```
dd if=/path/to/ISO of=/dev/sdX bs=4M; sync
```

Using `cp` :

```
cp /path/to/iso /dev/sdX
```

[How do I write a CD/DVD/BD image to a USB flash drive?](https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#write-usb)

> On a Linux machine, simply use the cp command, to copy an image to a USB flash drive:
>
> `cp <file> <device>`
>
> Alternatively you can also use dd:
>
> `dd if=<file> of=<device> bs=4M; sync`

Comment: I recently had problems creating a bootable Debian 11 USB from iso file with cp, dd and gnome-disks utility. What finally worked was balenaEtcher: https://www.balena.io/etcher/ Credits go to Adnan Shabor on linuxhint.com (https://linuxhint.com/make-a-debian-11-bootable-usb/).

Answer (score -1):

for making a pen drive bootable , first go to the boot mode by pressing the boot key. Then change the path of the boot strap loader  by changing the priority of the operating system.Or if this process still do not work ,try instaling the drivers of the USB.

Comment: All is working well when i am installing Linux mint.... Issue arises if and only if I am trying to install any non-mint os....

Comment: If my machine is off or in running "mode" the only way of going to "boot mode" is by pressing the reset button or power switch. Is that what you mean by "pressing the boot key"?